# Automatically Insert Date

Tags: excel, date

I am having a heck of a time trying to figure out how to have my table automatically update the date when data is entered. I want this for the entirety of column F, when data is input into any of the cells in column A (I would then like the corresponding cell in F to have the date updated. I have tried an "IF" statement, and numerous other ways. The data in the other cells, don't matter at all.

Anyone have any ideas?

Thanks

[Screenshot of Spreadsheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B2ysJ.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make the F column number format as "Date". Then apply following formula for entire F column. Whenever some data is entered in A column, respective F row will be updated with date.

=IF(LEN(A1)>0,TODAY()," ")

Comment: While this formula does work, it doesn't work as I imagined it would.What I found is that it updates continually to "TODAY" continually each time I open the file. What I want is it to automatically update the date as I enter data into the corresponding A-cell.

Any thoughts?